# Problem with creating "list of symbols" in latex

Tags: texstudio, nomenclature

I am trying to create `.tex` that helps me to collect a list of symbols which I will use in my thesis.

In main `.tex` I have written:

```
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
  \AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\columnwidth}}
  \let\abbrev\nomenclature
  \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of symbols and abbreviations used}
  \renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
  \setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
  \makenomenclature
```

in `list_of_symbols.tex`:

```
\cleardoublepage
\ihead[]{List of symbols and abbreviations used}
\printnomenclature
```

In the text I am using the following to full the list:

```
\nomenclature{AK}{\markup{A}cross \markup{K}ing}
```

If I run the main file, I will get an error `no file document.nls'. How to create it? Did I something wrong?

Comment: Have you invoked `makeindex`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you post your `MWE` as in executable format?